# Unable to Read REST Parameters in Tasklet / ItemReader

Tags: java, rest, parameters, spring-batch

i want to setup a new Batch Job.

This Job should receive a few Parameters from the Rest Interface (i am Using @EnableBatchProcessing for the automated JobScanning).

I only want the job to be performed once per rest call -> thats why i think a tasklet would be the weapon of choice. But i did not get @StepScope to work with a tasklet only Job (it seems as if there is no StepScope available without chunk but please correct me if i am wrong)...

My other idea was to create an ItemReader that reads the JobParameters and create a single Domain Object (from the Parameters) and then processes the Data and writes to a Dummy ItemWriter.

I tried to setup the ItemReader like this:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<BatchPrinterJob> setupParameterItemReader(
        @Value("#{jobParameters}") Map<String, Object> jobParameters) {

    ItemReader<BatchPrinterJob> reader = new ItemReader<BatchPrinterJob>() {

        @Override
        public BatchPrinterJob read()
                throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

            BatchPrinterJob job = new BatchPrinterJob();
            LOG.info(jobParameters.toString());
            return job;
        }
    };
    return reader;
}
```

i tried to start the job with a POST Request like this: myhost:8080/jobs/thisjobsname?name=testname

But the only thing that gets logged is the run.id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, i wrote my own Launcher for this Job based on your example:

```
@RestController
public class AutoPrintLaunchingController {

@Autowired
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
private AutoPrint autoprint;

@RequestMapping(value = "/jobs/AutoPrint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public void launch(@RequestParam("Drucker") String printer, @RequestParam("Fach") String fach,
        @RequestParam("Dokument") String doc, @RequestParam("DokumentParameter") String param) throws Exception {

    JobParametersBuilder jpb = new JobParametersBuilder();
    jpb.addString("Drucker", printer);
    jpb.addString("Fach", fach);
    jpb.addString("Dokument", doc);
    jpb.addString("DokumentParameter", param);
    jpb.addDate("dateInstant", Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));

    JobParameters jobParameters = jpb.toJobParameters();
    this.jobLauncher.run(autoprint.createAutoPrintJob(), jobParameters);
}

}
```

This is works as it required !

Answer (score 1):

> i think a tasklet would be the weapon of choice. But i did not get @StepScope to work with a tasklet only Job (it seems as if there is no StepScope available without chunk but please correct me if i am wrong)...

You can use `@StepScope` on a tasklet, here is an example:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public Tasklet tasklet(@Value("#{jobParameters['parameter']}") String parameter) {
    return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
        // use job parameter here
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    };
}
```

Then use the tasklet to create the step:

```
@Bean
public Step step() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
            .tasklet(tasklet(null))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you the code compiles, but the parameter does not evaluate to the Rest Parameter: 

I tried logging the Output but it always evaluates to null:

       `@Bean
 @StepScope
 public Tasklet tasklet(@Value("#{jobParameters['parameter']}") String parameter)              {
  return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
   LOG.info(chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters().toString());
   LOG.info("customParameter: " + parameter);
   return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
  };
 }`

This only logs the changing run.id + customParameter: null

Comment: In your rest controller, do you pass request parameters as job parameters? This answer shows an example, you need to make sure that the job parameter you are trying to get in the tasklet is correctly passed to job from your controller.

Comment: I guess that might be the problem. We are using the AutomaticJobRegistrarConfiguration that automatically scans for Jobs and creates endpoints for them. Is there a way to manually override the endpoint with the needed parameters for one Job ? or can i somehow tell the AutomaticJobRegistrar to scan for the requested Parameters ?

Comment: This is not related to how jobs are registered but how jobs are launched. What I mean is that your controller should make sure to launch the job with the parameter you need in your tasklet. Here is an example: https://github.com/mminella/LearningSpringBatch/blob/master/src/startingAJob/src/main/java/io/spring/batch/controller/JobLaunchingController.java#L44-L49